# laravel undefined offset 0 laravel 8 resources

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

hello i have this error : Undefined offset: 0 (View: /home/me/www/me/resources/views/contact.blade.php) i was try to create crud in admin panel for contact page. when i try to go in for edit this page, i have this error

Undefined offset: 0 (View: /home/.../www/.../resources/views/contact.blade.php) and if i remplace all data by  {{ dd($data) }}  i have this

```
Address 
 <script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl', addEventListener = function (e, n, cb) { e.addEventListener(n, cb, false); }; (doc.documentElement.firstElementChild || doc.documentElement.children[0]).appendChild(refStyle); if (!doc.addEventListener) { addEventListener = function (element, eventName, callback) { element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function (e) { e.preventDefault = function () {e.returnValue = false;}; e.target = e.srcElement; callback(e); }); }; } function toggle(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className, arrow, newClass; if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(oldClass)) { arrow = '▼'; newClass = 'sf-dump-expanded'; } else if (/\bsf-dump-expanded\b/.test(oldClass)) { arrow = '▶'; newClass = 'sf-dump-compact'; } else { return false; } if (doc.createEvent && s.dispatchEvent) { var event = doc.createEvent('Event'); event.initEvent('sf-dump-expanded' === newClass ? 'sfbeforedumpexpand' : 'sfbeforedumpcollapse', true, false); s.dispatchEvent(event); } a.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; s.className = s.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-(compact|expanded)\b/, newClass); if (recursive) { try { a = s.querySelectorAll('.'+oldClass); for (s = 0; s < a.length; ++s) { if (-1 == a[s].className.indexOf(newClass)) { a[s].className = newClass; a[s].previousSibling.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; } } } catch (e) { } } return true; }; function collapse(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className; if (/\bsf-dump-expanded\b/.test(oldClass)) { toggle(a, recursive); return true; } return false; }; function expand(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className; if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(oldClass)) { toggle(a, recursive); return true; } return false; }; function collapseAll(root) { var a = root.querySelector('a.sf-dump-toggle'); if (a) { collapse(a, true); expand(a); return true; } return false; } function reveal(node) { var previous, parents = []; while ((node = node.parentNode || {}) && (previous = node.previousSibling) && 'A' === previous.tagName) { parents.push(previous); } if (0 !== parents.length) { parents.forEach(function (parent) { expand(parent); }); return true; } return false; } function highlight(root, activeNode, nodes) { resetHighlightedNodes(root); Array.from(nodes||[]).forEach(function (node) { if (!/\bsf-dump-highlight\b/.test(node.className)) { node.className = node.className + ' sf-dump-highlight'; } }); if (!/\bsf-dump-highlight-active\b/.test(activeNode.className)) { activeNode.className = activeNode.className + ' sf-dump-highlight-active'; } } function resetHighlightedNodes(root) { Array.from(root.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-str, .sf-dump-key, .sf-dump-public, .sf-dump-protected, .sf-dump-private')).forEach(function (strNode) { strNode.className = strNode.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-highlight\b/, ''); strNode.className = strNode.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-highlight-active\b/, ''); }); } return function (root, x) { root = doc.getElementById(root); var indentRx = new RegExp('^('+(root.getAttribute('data-indent-pad') || ' ').replace(rxEsc, '\\$1')+')+', 'm'), options = {
 options.maxDepth)) { toggle(a); } } else if (/\bsf-dump-ref\b/.test(elt.className) && (a = elt.getAttribute('href'))) { a = a.substr(1); elt.className += ' '+a; if (/[\[{]$/.test(elt.previousSibling.nodeValue)) { a = a != elt.nextSibling.id && doc.getElementById(a); try { s = a.nextSibling; elt.appendChild(a); s.parentNode.insertBefore(a, s); if (/^[@#]/.test(elt.innerHTML)) { elt.innerHTML += ' ▶'; } else { elt.innerHTML = '▶'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } elt.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; } catch (e) { if ('&' == elt.innerHTML.charAt(0)) { elt.innerHTML = '…'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } } } } } if (doc.evaluate && Array.from && root.children.length > 1) { root.setAttribute('tabindex', 0); SearchState = function () { this.nodes = []; this.idx = 0; }; SearchState.prototype = { next: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return this.current(); } this.idx = this.idx < (this.nodes.length - 1) ? this.idx + 1 : 0; return this.current(); }, previous: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return this.current(); } this.idx = this.idx > 0 ? this.idx - 1 : (this.nodes.length - 1); return this.current(); }, isEmpty: function () { return 0 === this.count(); }, current: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return null; } return this.nodes[this.idx]; }, reset: function () { this.nodes = []; this.idx = 0; }, count: function () { return this.nodes.length; }, }; function showCurrent(state) { var currentNode = state.current(), currentRect, searchRect; if (currentNode) { reveal(currentNode); highlight(root, currentNode, state.nodes); if ('scrollIntoView' in currentNode) { currentNode.scrollIntoView(true); currentRect = currentNode.getBoundingClientRect(); searchRect = search.getBoundingClientRect(); if (currentRect.top < (searchRect.top + searchRect.height)) { window.scrollBy(0, -(searchRect.top + searchRect.height + 5)); } } } counter.textContent = (state.isEmpty() ? 0 : state.idx + 1) + ' of ' + state.count(); } var search = doc.createElement('div'); search.className = 'sf-dump-search-wrapper sf-dump-search-hidden'; search.innerHTML = ' 
 0 of 0<\/span> '+h+' ◀'+ ''+elt.innerHTML+' ▶'; } } } catch (e) { } }; })(document);
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1218
  #items: []
}
```

contact blade

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: abhi
 * Date: 10/20/2020
 * Time: 5:54 PM
 */?>


@extends('layouts.app')

<style>
    body {
        font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }

    .sidenav {
        height: 100%;
        width: 160px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #111;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }

    .sidenav a {
        padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: #818181;
        display: block;
    }

    .sidenav a:hover {
        color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    .main {
        margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
        font-size: 28px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
        padding: 0px 10px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
        .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
        .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
    }
</style>

@section('content')
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">


    {{--<div class="sidenav">--}}
        {{--<a href="/post">Post</a>--}}
        {{--<a href="/category">Categories</a>--}}
        {{--<a href="/footer">Footer</a>--}}
        {{--<a href="/society">Society</a>--}}
    {{--</div>--}}



    <section style="padding-top:60px;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            Update Contact Details...
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            @if(Session::has('status'))
                                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                    {{Session::get('status')}}
                                </div>
                            @endif
                            <form id="insert" method="POST" action="{{url('updatecontact')}}"
                                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="h1">Address</label>
                                    <input type="text" value="{{$data[0]->address}}" name="address" class="form-control"/>

                                    <label for="h2">Contact(1)</label>
                                    <input type="tel" value="{{$data[0]->contact1}}" name="contact1" class="form-control"/>

                                    <label for="h2">Contact(2)</label>
                                    <input type="tel" value="{{$data[0]->contact2}}" name="contact2" class="form-control"/>

                                    <label for="h2">Fax</label>
                                    <input type="tel" value="{{$data[0]->fax}}" name="fax" class="form-control"/>

                                    <label for="h2">E-mail</label>
                                    <input type="email" value="{{$data[0]->email}}" name="email" class="form-control"/>

                                    <br>
                                    <input type="hidden" value="{{$data[0]->id}}" name="rowid">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Details</button>

                            </form>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        function previewFile1(input) {
            var file1 = $(input).get(0).files[0];
            if (file1) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function () {
                    $('#previewImg1').attr("src", reader.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file1);
            }
        }

    </script>

@endsection
```

controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Mail\ContactMail;
use App\Models\Contact;
use App\Models\ContactDetails;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    function index(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $data['data'] = Contact::all();

        return view('contact', $data);
    }

    function updateContact(Request $request){
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $data['address'] = $request->address;
        $data['contact1'] = $request->contact1;
        $data['contact2'] = $request->contact2;
        $data['fax'] = $request->fax;
        $data['email'] = $request->email;


        $affected = DB::table('contacts')
            ->where('id', '=', $request->rowid)
            ->update($data);

        return back()->with('status', 'Contact Details are Updated');
    }

    function sendContact(Request $request){

        $contact = new ContactDetails();

        $contact->name = $request->name;
        $contact->email = $request->email;
        $contact->phone = $request->phone;
        $contact->msg = $request->message;

        $contact->save();

        $dataObject = new \stdClass();
        $dataObject->name = $request->name;
        $dataObject->email = $request->email;
        $dataObject->phone = $request->phone;
        $dataObject->msg = $request->message;

        Mail::to('mokoch.web@gmail.com')->send(new ContactMail($dataObject));

        return back()->with('status', 'Contact Details are Updated');
    }
}
```

i try to create update for contact and i was hosted this but i have this i dont know how resolve... because crud for footer and other work whithout problem. it's in laravel 8

Comment: You print the data using $data[0], and either your $data['data'] is empty or you dont have a 0 offset, try to debug before the index

Comment: Can you take a snipit of the dd() cant read a thing currently

Comment: when i change to data i have Undefined index: data

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I would refactor the following

```
$data['data'] = Contact::all();
```

to

```
$contacts = Contact::all();
```

Remember that `Contact::all();` is going to return an array of collections so you would need to loop through `$contacts` on your index view.

if you are trying to update a contact you need to get the specific contact first for example:

```
$contact = Contact::find($id);
```

Then in your blade you can simply use `$contact->email` instead of `$data[0]->email`

So in your situation you need to create a show method that accepts an `id` as a **parameter** then you can find the record you want to update and use the example above.

A good resource if you are new [CodersTape](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6HNs9OlV34)

Comment: when i change data to contat i have : Undefined variable: contact (View: /home/.../www/.../resources/views/contact.blade.php)

Comment: Remember to change the variable in your return statement